# How to disable firefox rendering for a program?

Tags: html, firefox

how can i disable the Firefox rendering? i would like to download and display pure html only for a program i have in java which use selenium api

Comment: What is "the Firefox rendering"? Where do you want to display it? Why can't you simply output the HTML to any textual control?

Comment: You have to post questions clearly. What is your objective?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your Reponse Headers

In C# I'd do

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
```

If you want the user to see the html code.

or

```
Response.ContentType ="application/octet-stream"
```

If you want the user to download the html code.

EDIT : In java it seams that it's the "contentType" attribute of your @page directive on the top of your .jsp files that'll change the response's header.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all angle brackets in returned content with `'&lt;' or '&gt;'`. This will render them as text representations of html tags instead of the browser parsing them.